# Are isometries always linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector space (over a field of characteristic zero) and $f : E \rightarrow E$ be an isometry fixing 0.

Must $f$ be linear in this case ?

Note : I am NOT assuming that the norm of $E$ comes from a quadratic form (otherwise I know the answer is yes, as per [Should isometries be linear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570139/should-isometries-be-linear)). I expect the answer to my question should be no, but I don't have any counter example.

Comment: Related: [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem).

Comment: Here's another related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866445/rigid-motion-on-mathbbr2-which-fixes-the-origin-is-linear/866471#866471

Comment: sorry, did not see that duplicate

Comment: I am sorry myself, because the post I had linked (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/example-of-a-non-linear-isometry) was considering isometries between possibly different spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) every bijective isometry between normed spaces, in particular between identical normed spaces, is affine. The linked paper also contains an example of injective non-affine isometry. See also [Should isometries be linear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570139/should-isometries-be-linear)

Comment: Is it obvious that every isometry between the same (finite dimensional) normed space is always surjective? EDIT: Ok, it is open by invariance of domain. The image is complete, thus closed. Surjectivity then follows using the connectivity of $E$.