# How to prove dimensions of Euclidean spaces is equal?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\vert \vert -\vert \vert$ be the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$ given by $\vert \vert x \vert \vert = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots x_n^2}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. If $(\mathbb R^m, \vert \vert - \vert \vert)$ is isometric to $(\mathbb R^n, \vert \vert - \vert \vert )$, then show that $m =n$.

I am struggling with the proof. I have dealt with linear isometries in Linear Algebra. In that case, assuming a linear mapping $\phi : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb R^n$ would require $\phi$ to be bijective. Since the mapping would be both injective and surjective, it would imply $m = n$. However, $\phi$ is not necessarily linear.

Using properties of isometry, I know $\phi$ is bijective continuous, preserves distance and has a continuous inverse. Here's what I tried. If $\phi(x)=y$, then $\vert \vert \phi(x) \vert \vert = \vert \vert y\vert \vert = \vert \vert x \vert \vert$. Then using standard notation,

\begin{align}
&\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} y_i^2 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} x_i^2\\
&\vert \vert \phi(x + h) \vert \vert = \vert \vert y + h'\vert \vert = \vert \vert x + h \vert \vert \\
\implies & \lim\limits_{h' \to 0} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(y_i + h'_i)^2 = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m} (x_i + h_i)^2
\end{align}

I can make $h', h$ arbitrarily small so continuity of $\phi$ holds irrespective of dimensions $m, n$. What can I do at this point? I don't know if I can use the condition of continuous inverse somehow. However, I feel since the inverse argument would be completely symmetrical, this proof should use contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

An isometry between euclidean spaces fixing the origin is necessarily linear. This is discussed for example in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872090/are-isometries-always-linear).

You can substract $\phi(0)$ to $\phi$ to insure that the origin is fixed. Then you are back to the linear case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fixing the origin? Are you refering to metric derived from norm? I am asking because I need this for an online course subjective assessment and the professor did not use a similar terminology in class.

Comment: I mean $\phi(0)=0$, where $0$ is the null vector.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. So any norm that fixes the origin is linear right? Hmm. I will need to prove that. But that's a good start. Thanks!

Comment: Any isometry that fixes the origin is linear. Recall that two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isometric if there is a bijective map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such  that $\|f(x)-f(y)\| = \|x-y\|$ for all $x$, $y$.