# Prove that a rigid motion is surjective and injective

Tags: linear-algebra, rigid-transformation

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $R$ and suppose $f: V\rightarrow V$ is a rigid motion.

Prove that $f$ is both injective and surjective.

So I know that a rigid motion is an isometry and is defined by the function  $f: V\rightarrow V$ such that $||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x - y||$ for all $x,y\in V$, where $V$ is an inner product space.

I'm struggling to figure out how to prove injectivity and surjectivity using that definition.

Any guidance on how to prove this?

Comment: @MatthewPilling: A rigid motion need not send $0$ to $0$.

Comment: To show $f$ is one-to-one, start with $u\neq v$; then check that $f(u)\neq f(v)$ by verifying that $f(u)-f(v)$ is not the zero vector.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the details, but surjectivity SHOULD be $f(y-f(0))=f(y)$, based on the idea that $f$ moves $0$ to $f(0)$,  and it is rigid, so to get to $y$ we just go back that amount

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I knew that :-p

Comment: @Alan: That equality is not true in general. Consider the map that first sends $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ on the plane, and then rotates $90$ degrees in the positive direction about the origin. If $y=(1,0)$, then $f(y-f(0)) = f(0,0) = (0,1)$, but $f(1,0) = (0,2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\ g(x)=f(x)-f(0)\ $ then $\ g\ $ must be an orthogonal linear transformation.  Here's an outline of a proof.

First,
$$
 \|g(x)\|=\|f(x)-f(0)\|=\|x\|\ ,
$$
and
\begin{align}\|g(x)-g(y)\|^2&=\|f(x)-f(0)-(f(y)-f(0))\|^2\\&=\|x-y\|^2\\
&=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\langle x,y\rangle\ ,
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}\|g(x)-g(y)\|^2&=\|g(x)\|^2+\|g(y)\|^2-2\langle g(x),g(y)\rangle\\
&=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\langle g(x),g(y)\rangle\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\langle g(x),g(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle\ .
$$
Now
\begin{align}
\langle g(x)&,g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle\\
&=\langle g(x),g(\lambda y+\mu z)\rangle-\lambda\langle g(x),g(y)\rangle-\mu\langle g(x),g(z)\rangle\\
&=\langle x,\lambda y+\mu z\rangle-\lambda\langle x,y\rangle-\mu\langle x,z\rangle\\
&=0\ .
\end{align}
Since this is holds for any $\ x\ $, we have, in particular,
\begin{align}
\langle g(\lambda y+\mu z),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle&=0\ ,\\
\langle g(y),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle&=0\ ,\ \text{and}\\
\langle g(z),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle&=0\ ,
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
&\|g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\|^2\\
&=\langle g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle\\
&=\langle g(\lambda y+\mu z),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle\\
&\hspace{1em}-\lambda\langle g(y),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle\\
&\hspace{1em}-\mu\langle g(z),g(\lambda y+\mu z)-\lambda g(y)-\mu g(z)\rangle\\
&=0\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ g(\lambda y+\mu z)=\lambda g(y)+\mu g(z)\ $, and so $\ g\ $ is linear.  Since $\ g(x)=0\ $ implies that
$$
\|x\|=\|g(x)\|=0\ ,
$$
and hence that $\ x=0\ $, it follows that $\ \ker g=\{0\}\ $, and so $\ g\ $ is injective.  It then follows from the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem#Stating_the_theorem) for finite dimensional spaces that $\ g\ $ is also surjective.

Thus, if $\ f(x)=f(y)\ $, then $\ g(x)=$$f(x)-f(0)=$$f(y)-f(0)=$$g(y)\ $, which implies $\ x=y\ $. So $\ f\ $ is also injective.  And if $\ z\in V\ $, and $\ y=g^{-1}(z-f(0))\ $, then $\ f(y)=g(y)+f(0)=z\ $, so $\ f\ $ is also surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Checking injectivity is straighfroward: if $v\neq w$, then $\lVert f(v)-f(w)\rVert = \lVert v-w\rVert \neq 0$, hence $f(v)\neq f(w)$. This proves injectivity.

Proving surjectivity seems to me to be trickier; can't think of a way right now other than going the long way around: using the fact that [a rigid motion that fixes $0$ is linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866445/rigid-motion-on-mathbbr2-which-fixes-the-origin-is-linear).

So say $f$ is a rigid motion. Then so is $g(x) = f(x)-f(0)$, because it's a rigid motion followed by a translation. But $g(0)=0$, so $g$ is actually linear. And since $g$ is one-to-one linear on a finite dimensional vector space, it is also onto. But if $g$ is onto, then so is $f$.

(I suspect there may be a clever way of showing it is onto, but finite-dimensionality needs to play a role and I can't come up with it right now).

Comment: Good answer! It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

@lonzaleggiera gave an excellent "algebraic proof" (+1).  Here are two alternative arguments: one geometric and one topological.  The topological one is  noteworthy as it takes a different route to most solutions, by not showing that any maps are linear.  However it uses [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) instead, which is actually less trivial to prove than linearity.  Credit for the topological solution to @PhoemueX for the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872090/are-isometries-always-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Variants of this question have been asked so many times I expect someone has also posted the geometric solution too, at some point.  In my view the one by @lonzaleggiera is the best of these 3, as it is the most succinct and self-contained, but the others are interesting in their own right.

---

Solution $2$ (Geometric):  Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with Euclidean norm.  Suppose that $g$ is a rigid motion of $V$, fixing the origin $O$. We will show that $g$ is linear.  Bijectivity of an arbitrary rigid motion follows.

The vectors $Z$ in the line segment $XY$  are characterized by the condition $||X-Y|| =||X-Z|| + ||Z-Y||$, so $g$ preserves line segments.

Let $\lambda\geq1$ and $X\in V$. Then $Y=\lambda g(X)$ is the unique vector satisfying $||Y||=\lambda||X||$ and $g(X)$ lies on the line segment $OY$.

As $X$ lies on the line segment $O(\lambda X)$, we know $g(X)$ lies on the line segment $O(g(\lambda X))$.  Further we know $||g(\lambda X)||=\lambda||X||$.  Thus $g(\lambda X)=\lambda g(X)$.

[image]

The cases $\lambda\leq0$ and $\lambda\in (0,1)$ follow analogously.

Now consider a pair of vectors $X,Y$.  We have a parallelogram $OX(X+Y)Y$.  Thus for $\delta\in (0,||X||)$, if $V_1$ lies in the line segment  $OX$, at distance $\delta$ from $O$, and $V_2$ lies in the line segment  $Y(X+Y)$, at distance $\delta$ from $Y$, then $||V_1-V_2||=||Y||$.

Applying $g$ to this configuration, we must obtain a parallelogram $O(g(X))(g(X+Y))(g(Y))$, as $||g(V_1)-g(V_2)||=||g(Y)||$, for all $\delta\in (0,||X||)$.  Thus $g(X+Y)=g(X)+g(Y)$.

[image]

---

Solution 3 (Topological):
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with Euclidean norm.  Suppose that $f$ is a rigid motion of $V$.  Then $f$ is clearly injective and continuous, and im$(f)$ is non-empty.

Let $Y$ be an accumulation point of im$(f)$.  Then we have a sequence of vectors $X_i\in V$ with $f(X_i)\to Y$ and $f(X_i)$ Cauchy, so $X_i$ is Cauchy.  Let $X_i\to X$.  Then by continuity, $f(X)=Y$, so im$(f)$ is closed.

By [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) we also know that im$(f)$ is open.  As it is also non-empty, by connectedness of $V$ we have that im$(f)$ is the whole of $V$.